# Why is the magnetic potential inside the centre of a square wire zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

Given a wire of square configuration, I found that the magnetic potential at the centre of that square is 0. I am a bit confused as to why this is the case, given that the magnetic field at the centre is non-zero. I was wondering what physical explanation to that might be (unless my result is incorrect).

Comment: The magnetic (vector) potential is gauge-dependent. That means that its value at any given point is (by itself) without any physical meaning. What gauge did you use?

Comment: Just think back to intro physics. Does $0$ gravitational potential energy mean $0$ gravitational force?

Answer (score 1):

In the Coulomb gauge, the potential vector is a polar vector, orthogonal to an anti symmetry plane.

For the square wire, the potential vector on the $Oz$ axis is orthogonal to $(O,x,z)$ and $(O,y,z)$ and so is $0$ on the $Oz$ axis.

This only show that the partial derivative along this axis is $0$.

But to compute the magnetic field along this axis, you need to know the partial derivative  along $Ox$ and $Oy$ and so, the magnetic field is not $0$ along the $Oz$ axis!